# Ruby, Rspec, and requiring test contoller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm new to Ruby (RoR) and rspec.

I have the basic project scaffold and a controller within `project/app/controllers/books_controller.rb`

Then I'm trying to setup rspec in `project/spec/controllers/book_spec.rb`

There also exists `project/spec/spec_helper.rb` that `book_spec.rb` requires. This file is where I'm trying to include the `books_controller.rb` file.

How do I include the `books_controller.rb` file so `book_spec.rb` has the Book object so when I run rspec, it works?

Currently I've tried things like `require_relative "../app/controllers/books_controller"` and it doesn't work. It gives me an error like:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController ... in 'require_relative'
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to manually include your controllers, just follow the rspec naming conventions and describe the desired object and everything will work fine.

Your controller spec should be named `books_controller_spec.rb`. That is the exact same name as your controller with a `_spec` added at the end. This is not a hard requirement but a highly suggested convention as a `book_spec.rb` really implies a `Book` model spec rather than a controller.

The critical part is that in your spec you describe the desired object, e.g.

```
describe BooksController do
  #...
end
```

You might also want to have a look at the [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) gem which provides some [useful generators](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/generators) for specs. Ideally you integrate with Rails so whenever you generate a new model or controller a new spec is created for you as well.

Comment: What should `spec_helper.rb` look like? Because I currently have `books_controller.rb` and now `books_controller_spec.rb`, which has `describe BooksController do ... end` in it. But when I run rspec from the project root, it still returns **uninitialized constant BooksController**

Comment: Use the `rspec-rails` gem and after `bundle install` issue `rails generate rspec:install`. This should provide a `spec_helper.rb` with sane defaults. Follow the links on my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize it would be that easy to implement into my preexisting project. Everything is working!